# why SVM regression (SMOreg) grayed out in weka?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, regression, svm

I have a dataset containing text documents. The training dataset classifies some documents as spam/ham. I need to use a model so that each test document will get a value between 0-1 (0 being spam, 1 being ham). I have used Naive Bayesian classifier which gives me probabilities of each test instance belonging to either ham or spam. But the SVM regression (SMOreg in weka) is always grayed out. I tried changing class labels to 0 and 1 (0=spam, 1=ham), still no luck.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

SMOreg is a **regression** method, while your problem is **classification**. WEKA automaticaly "grays out" unavaliable methods (which are not supported by your libraries and/or are not possible to use with your data).

Comment: Can you tell me how can i get probability of each test instance belonging to either class using SVM classifier? (sorry if this is a noob question, i am new to weka)

Comment: SVM does not return probability of being in a class. There are "tricks" to do so - like Platt's scaling (which is implemented in libSVM for example).

Comment: actually while using SMO classifier in weka, i checked "output predictions" in "More Options" and weka gave me probability distribution for each test instance in classifier output. I think those are the values i require, or they represent something else?

Comment: This is exactly Platt's scaling. It is not "pure" svm, but rather Logistic Regression trained on the SVM solution. It is a bit tricky, yet working - solution.

Comment: any comments regarding the downvote? Is this answer not accurate?